# Control not recognized the first time on the form

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am trying to follow along with some SiteCore Training material.  The directions are

> In the Grid Designer, in the Ribbon, in the Layout tab, in the Add group, click Control.
>
> In the Insert Control dialog, select the FieldRenderer item.
>
> The item path is: sitecore/Layout/Renderings/ System/FieldRenderer
>   Click OK

No problem so far.  But when I attempt to do the next step I nothing happens and there is an error in the console.

> In the Grid Designer, double click the FieldRenderer control.

[image]

Now in playing around while I was typing this up I notice that switching to the HTML tab and then back the Grid tab seem to "fix" this error.

But does anyone know why this happens in the first place and am I doing anything incorrectly that is creating this error?

I am using Chrome Version 40.0.2214.115 m

Comment: Which version of Sitecore?   This might help: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/581527

Comment: Sitecore version 6.5... I will have to look into this.  I found it interesting that it says "Note: Enabling the modal dialog boxes support by modifying the EnableDeprecatedWebPlatformFeatures group policy is no longer valid because of the recent changes in Chrome 39."  because that is not true, I had to set this in the policy manager to get any editor to appear.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know  of anyone using the developer center any more. Thing it's pretty much legacy.